# SAS: how to fix WAITFOR behavior in parallel sessions processing?

Tags: parallel-processing, sas

I'm running 3 parallel sessions in SAS and need to make sure they have all completed running before putting them together. I use WAITFOR command to do this but the behavior is not as expected.

I'm using base SAS 9.3

This is the code with which I signon into the sessions:

```
%macro open_sessions(n);
%let t=2;
%let j = %eval(&n. + 1); 

%do %while (&t. <=&j.);
%let r&t.=%str(xxx) xxx; 
options remote=r&t. comamid=tcp debug='connect=xxx'; 
options metaserver="xxx" 
metaport=xxx
metauser="xxx" 
metapass="&PSW." 
metaprotocol="bridge"; 
signon authdomain="xxx" wait=no Cmacvar=d&t.;
libname work_r&t. server=r&t. slibref=work;
options nolabel; 
%let t = %eval(&t. + 1); 
RDISPLAY r&t; 
%end;

%mend open_sessions;
```

Then I execute several

```
rsubmit r2;
...
endrsubmit;
rsubmit r3;
...
endrsubmit;
rsubmit r4;
...
endrsubmit;
```

And finally:

```
WAITFOR _ALL_ r2 r3 r4; (after there is other code)
```

At this point 2 alternative different things happen in different runs either
1. SAS shuts down, i.e. all windows close, including SAS itself, or
2. SAS waits endlessly as if some session was still running, but in reality all sessions have completed running (i.e. the cmacvar variables are all =0 and all outputs have been produced). If I try to submit other code to the sessions, I get this message: "Note: a display statement is currently executing. all subsequently submitted statements will not begin executing until its completion"

If I execute separately the code that comes before waitfor and then the code that comes after waitfor, everything goes fine.

I already tried the 2 solutions that sas.com proposes when you get the "Note: a display statement is currently executing..." message, but it didn't work. The 2 solutions are: 1. unflagging "Pop to the front when new data is displayed" for the output window (which was already unflagged), 2. rename the local files profile.sas7bcat and profile2.sas7bcat

I expect the code to run smoothly from start to end waiting when there is the waitfor statement but then resuming when all sessions are done with their tasks

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Have you tried contacting SAS support?

Comment: Yes, they said that the only supported use of waitfor is this: 
systask command "sas myprog1.sas" taskname=sas1;
systask command "sas myprog2.sas" taskname=sas2;
systask command "sas myprog3.sas" taskname=sas3;
waitfor _all_ sas1 sas2 sas3;

Comment: That's ridiculous. Have they not seen [their own code example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/63066/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1idin6oyrg4ygn18yo3lgexm515.htm) for MP connect?

Comment: Right! Today they are going to call me and I'll point this out, thanks. Going back to the problem, could it be that i need to specify process=something after the rsubmit?